# Is it preferable using flatmap multiple times in a single pipe of Mono<Object>

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, reactive-programming, project-reactor

As part of the development team, we want to build a non-blocking application for that we are building our application using Spring Reactor 3. So while using project reactor I have a list questions:

1. Is it a good practice using multiple flatMap in a single pipe and on a `Mono<object>`, like if there is a scenario of validating the info of an emp if all the details of emp is valid:

   ```
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public class Employee {
        private long empId;
        private String userName;
        private String password;

   }
   public class FlatMapExample{
   public Mono<Emplyoee> doValidate(Emplyoee emp){

       Mono.just(emp).flatMap(this::validateEmpId)
             .flatMap(this::validateUserName)
             .flatMap(this::validatePassword);
   }
   private Mono<Emplyoee> validateEmpId(Emplyoee e){
    Mono.just(emp).flatMap(//here some check on empId)
   }

   private Mono<Emplyoee> validateUserName(Emplyoee e){
    Mono.just(emp).flatMap(//here some check userName calling another method which is performing some extra checks like the format of username/ null or empty userName)
   }

   private Mono<Emplyoee> validatePassword(Emplyoee e){
    Mono.just(emp).flatMap(//here some check to validate password by calling another method)
   }

   }
   ```
2. Does flatMap cost more in terms of resources as compared to map?
3. If we will be using the map then the method called inside the map should return a simple object, for example in the above-mentioned case if we used the map then the return type of validateEmpId and other methods will be only Employee. So in these methods, we can not use the pipe, it will simple Java or we can use Java streams. So then it won't be a functional programming in my view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try simplify your validate api such as:

```
public Mono<Void> doValidate(Emplyoee emp){
  return validateEmpId(emp.getId())
    .then(validateUserName(emp.getUserName()))
    .then(validatePassword(emp);
}
private Mono<Void> validateEmpId(long id){
  // here some check on empId

  // if check ok return Mono.empty()
  // else return Mono.error(new YourException(...))
}
private Mono<Void> validateUserName(String userName){
  ...
}
private Mono<Void> validatePassword(Emplyoee emp){
  ...
}
```

No more `Mono.just(emp).flatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Validation of data is critical point, so in my opinion it would be better to synchronize this process.

Moreover if flatMap(this::validateEmpId) would return Mono.error(smth) your next validators wouldn't be execute, so you wouldn't be able to return full error message.

Author of [this](https://jeroenbellen.com/validating-springs-functional-endpoints/) article uses [Validator](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) in webflux (reactor) project, so I believe that in your example better way would be something like this:

```
public Mono<Emplyoee> doValidate(Emplyoee emp){
    /*validate */
    if(valid) {
        return Mono.just(emp);
    } else {
        return Mono.error(err);
    }
}
```